# Is there any way to store multiple value for one key in redis?

Tags: database, redis

I have data in this format:

```
 student_id:{ course: math
   day: sunday
   time: 16:00
  },
 { course: physics,
   day: friday,
   time: 20:00
  }
```

Could I store it in redis? One key and multiple structs!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple options for you:

1. Simple String value which use JSON string: Dump your data structure to Json and you can use any structures for value.
2. List / SortedSet / Hash: for multiple records, you can use list(or sorted set for range query). Or you can use hash for k-v dict as your value.

Answer (score 0):

The concept I think you're looking to learn about is called serialization. Serialization is the process of converting an object in your program into a binary string, a sequence of zeros and ones. This binary string can then be saved into a redis key.

There are a number of serialzation protocols that you can use. Some examples:

1. json
2. protocol buffers
3. parquet
4. hd5
5. msgbpack

etc.